# If statement in a do while loop being ignored

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-or, logical-and

I am trying to make a program that detects a user input and prints stuff based on that input. The input needs to have limits set however the if statements I set up are being ignored and I'm not quite sure why

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE 1
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int num;
    int exit; 

    exit = 0;

  printf("\nLab5 p1 by Chung - En Hou\n");

    num = 0;
    do{
        printf("\nEnter a number between 0 and 255:");
        //input
        scanf("%d", &num);
        //ignored if statement?
        if (num < 256 || num >= 0) {

            Sleep(250);
            printf("%d\n", num);
            Sleep(250);
            printf("%x\n", num);
            Sleep(250);
            printf("%c\n", num);

            printf("Press any button to Run the program again or press Esc to exit");

            exit = getch();
        }
        //else also ignored
        else {
            printf("\nthat number is turbo cringe please try again\n");
            printf("\nPress any button to Run the program again or press Esc to exit\n");
            exit = getch();
        }
    } while (exit != 27);


      return 0;
}
```

Comment: All numbers are either larger than or equal to zero or smaller than 256 -- or both. You probably want an `&&` in your condition.

Comment: You're not checking the return code from `scanf()`... Try typing "foobar" instead of a number and watch the fireworks go off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

```
    if (num < 256 && num >= 0) {
```

instead of

```
    if (num < 256 || num >= 0) {
```

That is the if statement checks whether the value of `num` is in the range `[0, 255]`

As for the expression in the if statement shown in the question then it will evaluate to true for any integer value of the variable `num`.